# Access $block inside Block body field that has PHP evaluator enabled

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

In template.php, I've added a variable to `$block` via `$vars['block']->member_login_url`, inside `theme_preprocess_block`.

I can access this variable in the `block.tpl.php` by: `<?php print $block->member_login_url; ?>`, but I would like to access it in the GUI block edit screen in Drupal (screenshot below of where I'm getting undefined variable errors).

The body field is using a text type with 'PHP Evaluator' enabled, but for some reason I can't figure out how to access Drupal variables, or block variables.

[image: getting variable error]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are assigning the value using object notation. I would have used `$vars['block']['member_login_url'] = blah` and then access the variable using `$member_login_url` in the tpl file, but you can output the available variables in the template using the php function `get_defined_vars()`

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. Only issue is I'm not trying to use it in the tpl file, I'm trying to access the variable in the Drupal GUI's Block->Configure Block screen, in a field that has PHP Evaluator enabled.

Comment: Have you had any luck regarding this?